# Online Legal References

Tags: discussion, faq, references

This thread is for legal references that may be most helpful and/or authoritative in addressing legal questions that arise on this site.

Answer (score 8):

*Note: Commercial sites listed in italics.*

### General/Multi-Jurisdiction Legal References

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_law)
- [DRAGNET](http://www.nyls.edu/library/research_tools_and_sources/dragnet/) (404)
- [WorldLII – World Legal Information Institute](http://www.worldlii.org/)
- [CommonLII – Commonwealth Legal Information Institute](http://www.commonlii.org/)
- [WEX International](http://www.law.cornell.edu/world)
- [CaseMine - United Kingdom and Ireland, India and the USA](https://www.casemine.com/judgments/)
- [AsianLII – Asian Legal Information Institute](http://www.asianlii.org/)

### United States Legal References

- [WEX Legal Information Institute](http://www.law.cornell.edu/wex) covers almost everything:
- [Federal Rules of Judicial Procedure](http://www.law.cornell.edu/rules)
- [U.S. Code](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text)
- [Code of Federal Regulations (CFR)](http://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text)
- [State Statutes by Topic](http://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/state_statutes)
- *[Justia](http://law.justia.com/)*
- *[FindLaw](http://public.findlaw.com/)*
- [Municode](http://www.municode.com/) (municipal codes)
- [Court Listener](http://www.courtlistener.com)
- [U.S. DoJ](http://www.justice.gov/usao/justice-101)
- [U.S. Copyright Office](http://www.copyright.gov/)
- [U.S. Patent & Trademark Office](http://www.uspto.gov/)
- [California OpenJustice](http://openjustice.doj.ca.gov/index.html)
- [California Courts Self-Help Center](http://www.courts.ca.gov/selfhelp.htm)
- [LSU Public Health Law](https://biotech.law.lsu.edu/map/index.htm)
- *[Pay sites used by professionals](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/2113/what-do-you-pay-for-lexis-bna-westlaw)*:

  - *[BNA](http://www.bna.com/)*
  - *[Lexis](http://www.lexisnexis.com/)*
  - *[Westlaw](http://westlaw.com)*
  - *[Loislaw](http://estore.loislaw.com/)*
  - *[Ravel](http://www.ravellaw.com/)*
  - *[PACER](http://www.pacer.gov/)*

### Other Countries

- [AustLII – Australasian Legal Information Institute](http://www.austlii.edu.au/)
- [BaiLII – British and Irish Legal Information Institute](http://www.bailii.org/)
- [CanLII – Canadian Legal Information Institute](http://www.canlii.org/)
- [Legislation.gov – United Kingdom](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/)
- [NZLII – New Zealand Legal Information Institute](http://www.nzlii.org/)
- [PacLII – Pacific Islands Legal Information Institute](http://www.paclii.org/)
- [SAfLII – Southern African Legal Information Institute](http://www.saflii.org/)
- [SCC – Canadian Supreme Court](https://decisions.scc-csc.ca/scc-csc/en/d/s/index.do?cont=&ref=&d1=&d2=&p=&or=)
- [Gesetzte im Internet - German laws, in big parts also available in English](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/Teilliste_translations.html)
- *[PNLD - England & Wales criminal justice legislation and guidance](https://www.pnld.co.uk/about-us)*
- [Victorian Legislation - laws of the Australian state of Victoria](https://www.legislation.vic.gov.au)
- [Code de la route - Belgian traffic laws](https://www.code-de-la-route.be/textes-legaux)
- [India Code - all central and state Acts](https://www.indiacode.nic.in)
- [Indian Kanoon - searchable case law](https://indiankanoon.org/browse/)
- [Kenya Law](http://kenyalaw.org:8181/exist/kenyalex/index.xql)
- [StGB - Austrian Criminal Code](https://www.jusline.at/gesetz/stgb)
- [ABGB - Austrian General Civil Code](https://www.jusline.at/gesetz/abgb)
- [légifrance - French codes etc](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/)

Comment: Out of curiosity, has there been a pressing need to lock the question (with the community-wiki reason)? I know it prevents people from posting new/separate answers, but it also prevents people from upvoting the "question" post (or commenting on it, I believe). It can always be locked if needed, but barring problems, I don't think it really *needs* to be.