# Are recommendations on law books, resources, and textbooks on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are recommendations on law books, resources, and textbooks on topic? An affirmative answer would veritably aid and benefit; both Linguistics SE and Philosophy SE (subjects which the law engage) do.

Following user 'Mr. A.' 's [request below](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328/are-recommendations-on-law-books-resources-and-textbooks-on-topic?noredirect=1#comment563_328), I exemplify the above with a question that interests him and the eligibility of which he wishes to know:is the following question an appropriate question:

> What is a good resource for learning how to do it yourself and file a declaratory judgment?"

Answer (score 2):

We have a [reference-request](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) tag. Some questions have been answered and other haven't; of those that haven't been answered, some are more related to the law than others, and some are more *answerable* than others. I suggest anyone requesting references or resources take heed of these questions and attempt to ask *answerable* questions.

Also note that we have a [Online Legal References](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/261/58) meta question (posted on Meta because list-style questions aren't on-topic).

As for your example, it might be acceptable if the question provided details on a jurisdiction.