# Are questions asking for help in how to search for past cases on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Pretty much what it says on the tin.  Is asking how a member of the public without any special access might search for past cases with a specific criteria on topic here? I didn't see anything in the meta for or against, so I thought I'd check first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is on topic. Check out the tag [legal-research](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal-research). Some jurisdictional tag wikis also have resources (e.g. [Canada's wiki](https://law.stackexchange.com/tags/canada/info)).

You might also find helpful resources [at this meta question](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261/online-legal-references).

Comment: Also, consider the [tag:legal-history] tag as well.